# windows 7 not showing correct wifi icon in taskbar

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, taskbar

I have windows 7 64bit and there's a problem with wifi icon as show in attached

[image: Photo]...

even if wifi is connected to network it's still showing another icon(i.e not connected icon).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That icon is the icon for a LAN cable. Indeed, it should show you the wifi icon instead. What happens if you plugin a LAN cable? Does the icon then change? And what if you unplug it? Also, have you tried reinstalling both LAN and WiFi drivers?

Comment: if i connect cable its the same nothing changed it's always showing the wrong icon

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling both drivers for LAN and WiFi?

Comment: Try to disable the network adapters and re-enable again. And check the service `Wi-fi Direct Services Connection Manager Service`.

Comment: @LPChip i reinstalled the drivers and it's working now :) ..... Thank for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That icon is the icon for a LAN cable. Indeed, it should show you the wifi icon instead.

What happens if you plugin a LAN cable? Does the icon then change? And what if you unplug it?

> if i connect cable its the same nothing changed it's always showing the wrong icon

Also, have you tried reinstalling both LAN and WiFi drivers?

> i reinstalled the drivers and it's working now :)